# Convert an array column into multiple columns Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, dataframe

I have a dataframe in the following format:

> 0 [[2387, 1098], [1873, 6792], ....
>
> 1 [0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, ...

I need to convert the array of first column into two futher columns. I have seen other such similiar questions but the solutions are given for smaller data, I have around 300 rows and can't write them all down manually. I have tried *`to_list()`* but I get an error when using it.

What code should I use to split it into two? Also, why is my dataframe not displaying in the form of columns rather in rows?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can convert your dataframe in this way:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

df = pd.DataFrame({0:[[2387, 1098], [1873, 6792],], 1:[0,1]})
arr = np.array(df.loc[:,0].to_list())
df2 = pd.DataFrame({0:arr[:,0], 1:arr[:,1], 2:df.loc[:,1]})
print(df2)
```

The result is:

```
      0     1  2
0  2387  1098  0
1  1873  6792  1
```

A second way to solve the problem (with a "moon" sample) is:

```
import sklearn
import sklearn.datasets

X, y = sklearn.datasets.make_moons()
pd.DataFrame({'x0':X[:,0], 'x1': X[:,1], 'y':y})
```

and the result is:

```
          x0        x1  y
0   0.981559  0.191159  0
1   0.967948 -0.499486  1
2   0.018441  0.308841  1
3  -0.981559  0.191159  0
4   0.967295  0.253655  0
..       ...       ... ..
95  0.238554 -0.148228  1
96  0.096023  0.995379  0
97  0.327699 -0.240278  1
98  0.900969  0.433884  0
99  1.981559  0.308841  1

[100 rows x 3 columns]
```

Comment: I replaced your line of code: df = pd.DataFrame({0:[[2387, 1098], [1873, 6792],], 1:[0,1]}) with df = pd.DataFrame(data).
data contains a moon dataset from scikit learn.

I copied the rest of your lines as it it. arr = np.array(df.loc[:,0].to_list()) line gives me a value error of:
ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-7-2a0be59c6b12> in <module>
----> 1 arr = np.array(df.loc[:,0].to_list())

ValueError: could not broadcast input array from shape (200,2) into shape (200)

Comment: A moon dataset in sklearn is under the form (X,y) where X.shape is (200,2) and y.shape is (200,). In this case, the better way to separate columns is to write:

Comment: pd.DataFrame({'x0':X[:,0], 'x1': X[:,1], 'y':y})

Comment: I will add that in my answer cause one cannot write code in comments ...

Answer (score 1):

**EDIT:**

Maybe it looks strange but you can use `.str[0]` to get first column from lists in `DataFrame`.

```py
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame({0:[[2387, 1098], [1873, 6792],], 1:[0,1]})

new_df = pd.DataFrame({
              0: df[0].str[0], 
              1: df[0].str[1], 
              2: df[1]
         })

print(new_df)
```

---

**OLDER:**

Using `apply()` with `pandas.Series` you can convert first column into new `DataFrame` with two columns

```py
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame({0:[[2387, 1098], [1873, 6792],], 1:[0,1]})

new_df = df[0].apply(pd.Series)

print(new_df)
```

Result:

```
      0     1
0  2387  1098
1  1873  6792
```

And later you can assing them back to old `DataFrame

```py
df[2] = df[1]       # move `[0,1,...]` to column 2
df[[0,1]] = new_df  # put `new_df` in columns 0,1
```

Result:

```
      0     1  2
0  2387  1098  0
1  1873  6792  1
```

Or you can copy column `[0,1,...]` from old `df` to `new_df`

```py
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame({0:[[2387, 1098], [1873, 6792],], 1:[0,1]})

new_df = df[0].apply(pd.Series)
new_df[2] = df[1]

print(new_df)
```

---